# Required argument in the callback function does not work in Redux Framework

Tags: wordpress, redux-framework

I'm creating my theme options using Redux Framework. In our config file I am using a callback function which does not seem to work with the required argument. Here is the config for a field.

```
Redux::setSection( $opt_name, array(
        'title'      => __( 'Title', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
        'id'         => 'switch_buttonset-set',
        'desc'       => __('Select the Site Title'),
        'subsection' => true,
        'fields'     => array(
            array(
                'id'       => 'opt-button-set',
                'type'     => 'button_set',
                'title'    => __( 'My Title', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
                'subtitle' => __( 'My Sub Title', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
                'desc'     => __( 'Some description', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
                'options'  => array(
                    '1' => 'Default Title',
                    '2' => 'Custom Title',
                ),
                'default'  => '1'
            ),
            array(
                'id'       => 'my_id',
                'type'     => 'callback',
                'required' => array('opt-button-set','equals','2'),
                'title'    => __( 'Test Hidden Field', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
                'desc'     => __('Some Description'),
                'callback' => 'my_callback'
),
```

And here is my sample callback function

```
function my_callback(){

    echo 'Some callback functions here'
}
```

The problem is the **required** argument does not work and the field continues to be visible regardless of the option chosen. I do not find any documentation as well regarding this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I think the required option is not yet available in the callback fields.

For the moment you can use a jQuery function to show or hide you callback field. Here is the code you need for your case:

```
function my_callback(){
   echo '<fieldset id="my_id" class="redux-field-container redux-field" data-id="my_id" data-type="callback">';
   echo 'Some callback functions here'
   echo '</fieldset>';
}

add_action('admin_head', 'my_action_javascript');

    function my_action_javascript() { 
    ?>
       <script type="text/javascript" >

       jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

           // input#opt-button-set -> This field is hide in you switch, but determine the value of the switch
           if ($('input#opt-button-set').val() == 0) {
               $('#my_id').hide;
           } else {
               $('#my_id').show;
           };   

        });

       </script>
    <?php }
```